# Integrating the following function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-measure

I am asked to evaluate the integral
$$\int_{R^n}e^{-\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2x_i^2}\,dx$$
given that $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_n$ are real numbers different from $0$.

I am clueless on how to approach this, since I have never been exposed to these types of integrals. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your integral is equal to $\prod_{i=1}^n \int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-a_i^2x_i^2} dx_i$.

Comment: How do you notice that?

Comment: @user372003 It's an application of [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)

Comment: @rubik: I mean, Fubini's theorem is not how you *notice* it, just how you prove that what you noticed is correct.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By Fubini,
\begin{align*}
I&=\int_{{\bf{R}}^{n}}e^{-a_{1}^{2}x_{1}^{2}}\cdots e^{-a_{n}^{2}x_{n}^{2}}dx_{1}\cdots dx_{n}\\
&=\int_{{\bf{R}}}\cdots\int_{\bf{R}}e^{-a_{1}^{2}x_{1}^{2}}dx_{1}\cdots e^{-a_{n}^{2}x_{n}^{2}}dx_{n}\\
&=\left(\int_{\bf{R}}e^{-a_{1}^{2}x_{1}^{2}}dx_{1}\right)\cdots\left(\int_{{\bf{R}}}e^{-a_{n}^{2}x_{n}^{2}}dx_{n}\right)\\
&=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{|a_{1}|}\cdots\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi}}{|a_{n}|}.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 12):

The function is measurable because it is continuous and, also, positive. By the [Fubini-Tonelli Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem),
$$
\begin{aligned}\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\exp\left({-\sum_{i=1}^na_i^2x_i^2}\right)\,dx&=\prod_{i=1}^n\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-a_i^2x_i^2}\,dx_i=\prod_{i=1}^n\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-a_i^2x^2}\,dx\right)\\&=\left(\frac{1}{|a_1\cdots a_n|}\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2}\,dx\right)^n=\frac{(\sqrt{\pi})^n}{|a_1\cdots a_n|}.
\end{aligned}$$

---

In case you are not familiar with the [Gaussian Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral), here is a quick result.

Applying the previous theorem and a change of variable to $(\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2}\,dx)^2\,$ we obtain
$$\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2}\,dx\right)^2=\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-x^2}\,dx\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-y^2}\,dy=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dxdy=\int_{]0,+\infty[\times]0,2\pi[}re^{-r^2}\,drd\theta=\pi.$$
Take the square root of both sides, and the result follows.